# Not getting the form data loaded into [log:Zend_View_Abstract:private]

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-view

I assigned
 `$this->view->form = $form` (form instance) and now trying to display the content in layout.phtml using 
`echo $this->form;`
but not displaying anything. I tried to check contents using 
`print_r($this);` 
and I see no data loaded into `[log:Zend_View_Abstract:private]`. 
Could anyone please help me on how to get data loaded in phtml file.

AuthForm.php

```
class forms_AuthForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setName('login');

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username','username');
        $username->setLabel('Username:')
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->setOptions(array('class'=>'longfield'));

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('password','password');
        $password->setLabel('Password: *')
                 ->setRequired(true);

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit','submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Login');

        $this->addElements(array($username, $password,$submit));
    }
}
```

And AuthController.php

```
$form = new forms_AuthForm();
$this->view->form = $form;
```

Regrds
kiran

Comment: Could you provide some code that you use for your form, and in a controller?

Comment: Yes i edited please check it and help me...i am trying from last 2 days for this but it couldn't work..

Comment: Good advice: You should define your form in `init()` method, not in constructor.

Comment: The form looks ok. Check if you have decorators, $form->getDecorators()

Comment: @singles...Its not working..getting same prob...

Comment: @user594791..ur method also not working...same prob..

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure, but i think you have to assign the form to the layout not the view.

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$form =  new forms_AuthForm();
$layout->form = $form;
```

and in your **layout.phtml**

```
echo $this->layout()->form;
```